# C# Winforms Cefsharp with Adblock

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have developed my own web browser via `cefsharp`.
I mainly use it to watch Youtube videos. The browser has a timer that ends the application after a while.

I myself believe that Adblock is unfairly robbing small Internet sites.
But the double ad at the beginning of the video on Youtube (and some YouTubers add more ads at the beginning of the video) drastically shorten the watch time.

Is there any way to add the adblock extension to the browser based on `cefsharp`?

Comment: Not at the moment no. Extension support is very limited and unable to load complex extensions like ad block.

Comment: @amaitland are there any light weight alternatives or work arounds? For example importing a js-only adblock library using `ExecuteJavaScript`?

Comment: In theory yes you could use a JavaScript adblock library. It's not something that I've tried personally